# Reloading an object not working in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I am trying to test a controller method with the following code:

```
it "should set an approved_at date and email the campaign's client" do
  @campaign = Campaign.create(valid_attributes)

  post :approve, id: @campaign.id.to_s

  @campaign.reload
  @campaign.approved_at.should_not be(nil)
end
```

However, when I run this test, I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: @campaign.reload
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Campaign without an ID
```

When I run the analagous lines in the rails console, the reload works and the value is set as I need it to be.  Why isn't reload working for me when I run the code in an rspec test?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching to FactoryGirl:

```
  @campaign = FactoryGirl.create(:pending_approval_campaign)
  @campaign.approved_at.should be(nil)

  post :approve, id: @campaign.id.to_s

  @campaign.reload
  @campaign.approved_at.should_not be(nil)
```

That works as intended

Answer (score 3):

Two possible places for errors.

1. object creation. i.e.`@campaign = Campaign.create(valid_attributes)` Your object may not be created correctly. I suggest you to use `create!` instead of `create` in the test so that any error will be thrown.
2. Controller. When controller expect to find the object with an integer id, you feed it a string. That may also be the problem. I suggest you not to convert the id into string. If for GET, you can do that though not necessary. If for POST, converting to string is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would run a test to ensure a `Campaign` record is actually being created:

```
@campaign = Campaign.create(valid_attributes)
puts @campaign.id
```

`.reload` is the first place in your code that a nil `@campaign` would flag an error (since you can call `.to_s` on a nil object)